# Error: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens (ServiceAccountCredentials)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, credentials

I recently updated the [SignedJwtAssertionCredentials to ServiceAccountCredentials](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/issues/401).

**Code Snippet:**

```
SUB = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXXX.com"
scopes = ["XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]

json_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "XXXXXXXXX.json")
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(json_file, scopes=scopes)

delegated_credentials = credentials.create_delegated(SUB)
http = httplib2.Http()
http = delegated_credentials.authorize(http)
return build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=http)
```

**Error:**

> File "/base/data/home/apps/project_name/main.py", line 867, in authorize
>           return build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=http)
>       File "/base/data/home/apps/project_name/lib/oauth2client/util.py", line 128, in positional_wrapper
>           return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
>       File "/base/data/home/apps/project_name/lib/apiclient/discovery.py", line 193, in build
>           resp, content = http.request(requested_url)
>       File "/base/data/home/apps/project_name/lib/oauth2client/transport.py", line 159, in new_request
>           credentials._refresh(orig_request_method)
>       File "/base/data/home/apps/project_name/lib/oauth2client/client.py", line 744, in _refresh
>       self._do_refresh_request(http)
>       File "/base/data/home/apps/project_name/lib/oauth2client/client.py", line 812, in _do_refresh_request
>       raise HttpAccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg, status=resp.status)
>       HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method.

**What I've done:**

I delegated [domain-wide authority](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority) using the Client ID (*Google Cloud Platform* > *IAM & Admin* > *Service accounts* > *View Client Id*) which I authorized in the G Suite domain's admin console following the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority).

[image]

*I thought this would fix the problem but the next day, same error message. What is the issue?*

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the oauth2client build is trying to refresh the access token but a service account can't refresh the access token for sub account credentials with that method.

What if you skip the two http lines and just do:

```
SUB = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXXX.com"
scopes = ["XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]

json_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "XXXXXXXXX.json")
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(json_file, scopes=scopes)

delegated_credentials = credentials.create_delegated(SUB)
return build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=delegated_credentials)
```

passing the `credentials` instead of the authorized `http` object.

Comment: I was just able to test this solution recently which did not work for me, unfortunately. Error: `build() got an unexpected keyword argument 'credentials'`.

Comment: I wonder if you have an old version of the google python api?  The current version does have "credentials" as an argument: https://google.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.discovery-module.html#build